# How can i recording sound or songs from my device to my app? (not from mic)

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Is there a way to record sound but not through the microphone but through the internal sound device?

example: if i hear some song through my device / so i want to record it real time in the best quality like "line in" record.

in the regular recording in know it's the way
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

Comment: This post might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815850/forcing-mediarecorder-to-use-internal-microphone

Comment: Thanks but that i already know how to do recording.  My question was how I internally recording Songs in real time from my device .(not from mic)

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/18116244/648313 and this article http://xzpeter.org/?p=254, according to its author you will need to recompile Android sources in order to capture sound produced by your device

Comment: Thank you guys. I understand that it is really complicated